# Hide sortable placeholder when droppable hoverClass is triggered

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, nested-sortable

I have built my own nested ul-tree menu. The tree li-items are sortable, even in several levels using jQuery sortable() and droppable(). You just drag-n'-drop.

So, my problem now is that both "sortable() placeholder" and "droppable() hoverClass" are highlighted when dragging a item over the other items droppable()'s zones.

Here are my current code:

http://jsfiddle.net/PeterWesterlund/8KDur/89/

**The question:** How do I get the sortable placeholder to **not be highlighted** when the droppable() hover is triggered?

So only the place where the selected item will be placed are highlighted.

Comment: I have not yet managed to solve this problem. Does not anyone know how to do? :(

Answer (score 2):

had exactly the same problem. my solution is

#### Sortable

```
$(".scrollPane", ui).sortable({
    //...
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight myPlaceholder"
})
```

#### Droppable

```
$( container ).droppable({
    //...
    over: function( event, ui ){
        $(this).parent().addClass("hide-placeholder")
    },
    out: function( event, ui ){
        $(this).parent().removeClass("hide-placeholder")
    }
})
```

#### CSS(less)

```
.hide-placeholder{
    .myPlaceholder {
        visibility:hidden;/*display:none*/
    }
}
```

wished there was some kind of integration/communication between these different d&d concepts too.

Comment: activate/deactivate are better events than over and out for this   because placeholder will be displayed even when the cursor with dragged item is "out" (put move "over" and than remove aside) .

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing this problem now, and I made this gif to illustrate:

[image: Sortable + Droppable]

It’s really annoying how the placeholder won’t go away when dragging above the first connected Sortable (and probably also below the last one), but I think it’s by design. If I release the dragged item on the Droppable in the top, it will visually end up as the first item in the Culture section, but programmatically it will be set to Issue Cover and revert to its original position in the People section.

Hiding the placeholder using CSS, or removing it using JS, only creates an offset that isn’t even corrected using hacks, like tapping into jQUI’s internals: `$.ui.ddmanager.prepareOffsets($.ui.ddmanager.current, null);`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain I understand completely what you are asking but by using the property:`tolerance: "fit"` you can set different tolerances for how the drop is handled.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8KDur/157/)

Here is a list of possible options:

> Tolerance
>
> Specifies which mode to use for testing whether a draggable is 'over' a droppable. Possible values: 'fit', 'intersect', 'pointer', 'touch'.
>
> fit: draggable overlaps the droppable entirely
>   intersect: draggable overlaps the droppable at least 50%
>   pointer: mouse pointer overlaps the droppable
>   touch: draggable overlaps the droppable any amount
>
> Code examples
>
> Initialize a droppable with the tolerance option specified.
>   `$( ".selector" ).droppable({ tolerance: "fit" });`
>   Get or set the tolerance option, after init.

`//getter`

`var tolerance = $( ".selector" ).droppable( "option", "tolerance" );`

`//setter`

`$( ".selector" ).droppable( "option", "tolerance", "fit" );`

More information can be found [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/) under options.

Comment: I apologize for my hesitant English. I have tried with 'tolerance', but it doesn't work. The red placeholder-1px-line is shining somewhere all the time when I'm dragging an li-element over the other li-elements. I want the sortable()'s placeholder to be removed on droppable hover. Try for your self: http://jsfiddle.net/PeterWesterlund/8KDur/159/. When you dragging an element over the tree, the red color sometimes appears on two places at the same time. That is not user friendly.

Comment: I see now.  You would only like one red thing to be up at a time, whether it is the 1px bar or the highlighted element.  I have altered the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8KDur/173/) slightly to take you another step forward.  Using the `over` property you are able to call a function as something is dragged over a droppable.  What I have done is simply removed the 1px bar when you drag something over, however it does not reappear when you drag it off.  You will need to do this using the `out` parameter and reenable that 1px bar.  This isn't a full solution to your problem but I hope it helps.

Comment: Well, I was hoping that there would be a better solution. Maybe that `sortable()` and `droppable()` was able to talk to each other a little bit more. That I could affect placeholders state IF hoverClass exist or something like that.

Comment: Is there really no one else who had this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is, put this in your sortable option list:

```
refreshPositions: true
```

Now you dont have to hide anything anymore!